# OGR GeometryReference Intersects() method with OSGB projection causing crash

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, intersect

I'm trying to use the GeometryReference.Intersects() method to see if a feature within a grid intersects with another polygon. I have tried it in the QGIS python console (windows) and directly on linux, and it crashes in both cases.

EDIT: I have tried the same code with the data reprojected to UTM, which is working. So possibly it is a problem with using the Intersect method the the OSGB projection (EPSG: 27700)

If possible I would like to know what is going wrong, or alternatively if there is another method of checking if two features intersect within python.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

grid_ds = driver.Open("test_grid.shp")

poly_ds = driver.Open("test_poly.shp")

grid_layer = grid_ds.GetLayer()
poly_layer = poly_ds.GetLayer()

poly_geom = poly_layer[0].GetGeometryRef()
grid_geom0 = grid_layer[0].GetGeometryref()

grid_geom0.Intersects(poly_geom)
```

[Here is a link to some example datasets](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/myn0nth9s54yr6t/AACPgHkzzwTI-vDvrmxIpc1qa?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold a reference to the feature you are grabbing.  It's described more here:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

grid_ds = driver.Open("test_grid.shp")

poly_ds = driver.Open("test_poly.shp")

grid_layer = grid_ds.GetLayer()
poly_layer = poly_ds.GetLayer()

poly_feat = poly_layer[0]
grid_feat = grid_layer[0]

poly_geom = poly_feat.GetGeometryRef()
grid_geom0 = grid_feat.GetGeometryRef()

print(grid_geom0.Intersects(poly_geom))
```